# Using pip.conf with --extra-index-url to a restricted mirror behind a private network causes connection timeouts when not on the private network

Tags: python, pip

My workplace has a privately hosted PyPI mirror only accessable from a specific ip address, which is easily accessed via VPN or whilst in the office, as it is ip-restricted.  This allows us to `pip install` private packages which we use.

To use the mirror, I have specified `--extra-index-url` inside `pip.conf`, and while running a VPN, can use `pip install` just fine.

What I'd like to be able to do is to use `pip install` for publicly available packages while *not* connected to a VPN.  When I try to do this to install a simple publicly available package from PyPI's public mirrors, however, pip tries to connect 5 times (at a timeout of 15s each retry) to the private mirror which it cannot access due to the lack of VPN.  The error is shown below:

`$ pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f36c0bd25c0>, 'Connection to devpi.*REDACTED*.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')'`

As I use the same machine for work and personal use, I shouldn't be connected to the work VPN always when using pip, so this isn't really an option.  I have come across one workaround, which is to run `export PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/dev/null` in a terminal before running `pip install`, but this is a tedious process to go through every time I want to install a package.

Is there a way that I can get pip to look for the package in the public mirror first before trying to connect to an inaccessible URL?  Alternatively, are there some other workarounds which might be a bit cleaner, such as reducing the number of retries or setting the timeout time to be shorter than 15s?

Comment: Have you changed the value for `--index-url` in your pip.conf? index-url is pointing to https://pypi.python.org/simple by default and is always used. Anything specified by `--extra-index-url` will be used additionally to `--index-url` I'm pretty sure it should just work even if you're not connected to the VPN.

Comment: No, I have not changed the value for `--index-url`.  It does *work* without being connected to the VPN, but only after 5 connection timeouts.  It then connects to pypi.python.org/simple and retrieves the package.  Unfortunately, it also does this for every dependent package as well, so downloading a package is taking 75s * number of packages including dependencies.

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same issue, I have also not touched `--index-url` any updates?

Comment: I have the same problem. Is this resolved with some kind of hotfix?